# Facebook log in button will not call callback function

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am not sure I understand how it should be done.

First there is the `FB` button, which appears on the screen and take me to the FB log in page to confirm.

Even if this button *has no* `onclick` it takes me to the log in window anyway, but I added `onclick` and define a function :

```
<div onclick="login();" class="fb-login-button" data-width="300" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false" ></div>
```

The function is inside a `js` file and is :

```
  function login()
      {
          console.log("connecting...."); 
                 FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.status === 'connected') {
                      console.log("connected");
                      testAPI();
                    } else {
                      console.log("not connected");
                    }
                  });

      }
```

**Nothing** will be printed, even not "connecting..." even when I click the FB button and even when i successfully logged in.
No errors.

How it should be done ?
I want to log him in, call a function which approve me he is in, and extract his details.

Comment: developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/… try this link and second link is codexworld.com/login-with-facebook-using-javascript-sdk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing two different concepts, you can either use the official login button OR use `FB.login` of the JavaScript SDK. The login button only needs "onlogin" and handles everything else for you automatically, as you can see in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/

If you want to use `FB.login`, use a random div (or any HTML tag) instead:

```
document.getElementById('loginBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    FB.login((response) => {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //user just authorized your app
            document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }, {scope: 'email,public_profile'});
}, false);
```

More information: https://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: yep. just figured it out and see your asnwer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Using code inline is bad practice, you need to assign an ID or Class to the div and call function against it  eg:

```
<div class="test">Click me!</div>

$('div.test').click(function(){
    login();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is exactly how facebook show to do it, I am not sure they have bad practice.

Comment: Can you post the code where you link the JS maybe its the issue

Comment: I think bad practice or not, the question was - why is this function not being called at all ?

Comment: Maybe the Javascript file is not linked properly. I dont see any other reason why

Comment: Does it matter when I link this file ? before or after the FB SDK init ? I have this as the last link :      <script src="../javascripts/FacebookSDK.js"></script>

Comment: No it doesn't matter. If the FB SDK is loaded successfully or not it should not affect this. The exact issue is the method is not getting called which i suppose is a javascript or HTML error. Have you tried other code in the file? and is it being loaded successfully? (the js file)

Comment: the click listener is not the problem here and just a side note, not an answer to the question. also, jquery is overkill for a simple click event listener.